# Determining if a query is in a string

Tags: python

I have a list of query terms, each with a boolean operator associated with them, like, say:

```
tom OR jerry OR desperate AND dan OR mickey AND mouse
```

Okay, now I have a string containing user-defined input, `inputStr`.

My question is, in Python, is there a way to determine if the string defined by the user contains the words in the "query"?

I have tried this:

```
if ('tom' or 'jerry' or 'desperate' and 'dan' or 'mickey' and 'mouse') in "cartoon dan character desperate":
    print "in string"
```

But it doesn't give the output i expect.
As you can see, I don't care about whether the query terms are ordered; just whether they are in the string or not.

Can this be done? Am I missing something like a library which can help me achieve the required functionality?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: The reason yours didn't work is because the `and`/`or` operators are boolean. Your expression boils down to `if True in "cartoon..":

Comment: Yup, I realise that one now. Having a look round the Internet for something that might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether any of the words in a list are in the string:

```
any(word in string for word in lst)
```

Example:

```
# construct list from the query by removing 'OR', 'AND'
query = "tom OR jerry OR desperate AND dan OR mickey AND mouse"
lst = [term for term in query.split() if term not in ["OR", "AND"]]

string = "cartoon dan character desperate"
print any(word in string for word in lst)
```

If you use `re.search()` as [@jro suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785685/determining-if-a-query-is-in-a-string/7785714#7785714) then don't forget to escape words to avoid collisions with the regex syntax:

```
import re
m = re.search("|".join(map(re.escape, lst)), string)
if m:
   print "some word from the list is in the string"
```

The above code assumes that `query` has no meaning other than the words it contains. If it *does* then assuming that `'AND'` binds stronger than `'OR'` i.e., `'a or b and c'` means `'a or (b and c)'` you could check whether a string satisfies query:

```
def query_in_string(query, string):
    for term in query.split('OR'):
        lst = map(str.strip, term.split('AND'))
        if all(word in string for word in lst):
           return True
    return False
```

The above could be written more concisely but it might be less readable:

```
def query_in_string(query, string):
    return any(all(word.strip() in string for word in term.split('AND'))
               for term in query.split('OR'))
```

#### Example

```
query = "tom OR jerry AND dan"
print query_in_string(query, "cartoon jerry")   # -> False no dan or tom
print query_in_string(query, "tom is happy")    # -> True tom
print query_in_string(query, "dan likes jerry") # -> True jerry and dan
```

If you want to reject partial matches e.g., `'dan'` should not match `'danial'` then instead of `word in string` you 
could use `re.search()` and add `'\b'`:

```
re.search(r"\b%s\b" % re.escape(word), string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant post. :) Superb! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "cartoon dan character desperate"
>>> l = ['dan', 'mickey', 'mouse']
>>> print re.search('(%s)' % '|'.join(l), s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0233AA60>
>>> l = ['nothing']
>>> print re.search('(%s)' % '|'.join(l), s)
None
```

Where `s` is the string to search in and `l` is a list of words that should be in `s`. If the search function doesn't return `None`, you have a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ('tom' or 'jerry' or 'desperate' and 'dan' or 'mickey' and 'mouse') in "cartoon dan character desperate"
```

does not mean what you think it means, because the parentheses cause the `or` and `and` operations to be evaluated first, e.g:

```
>>> "tom" or "jerry" or "desperate" and "dan" or "mickey" and "mouse"
'tom'
```

... so your `if`-clause really means `if 'tom' in "cartoon dan character desperate"`.

What you probably meant was something like:

```
if ('tom' in inputStr) or ('jerry' in inputStr) or ('desperate' in inputStr and 'dan' in inputStr) or ('mickey' in inputStr and 'mouse' in inputStr)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you, Kimvais -- thank you so much. :)